# Eliminate duplicates of several arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays:

```
array1 = [ 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
array2 = [   5,   5,   7,   5]
array3 = [true,true,true,true]
```

I was wondering if there is any easy way (maybe with lodash) to eliminate the duplicates and end with this:

```
array1 = [ 'A', 'B', 'A']
array2 = [   5,   5,   7]
array3 = [true,true,true]
```

I know I can do a function and compare the previous value, but is there a more clever way to do it?

**Update**
Please note that I don't need to eliminate the duplicates of each array.
What I looking is a way to eliminate the duplicates "vertically"

**Update 2**
Please note that each "column" is a record.

`record1 = ['A',5,true]
record2 = ['B',5,true]
record3 = ['A',7,true]
record1 = ['B',5,true]`

Comment: You second examples all still have duplicates... --- The easiest way is to use `[...new Set(array1)]` from ES2015.

Comment: you are just removing the last element from your input arrays..

Comment: With Lodash is quite simple, actually. You could use `_.difference(array, [values])`. Reference [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Actually, that's the point. I only want to eliminate the duplicate taking into account all the arrays.
If you see,  'B', '5', 'true' is duplicated "vertically"

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, each "column" is a "record" and you want to eliminate duplicate records?

Comment: @JordanRunning that's correct

Comment: Are you looking for an in-place solution (remove duplicates from given arrays) or a immutable solution producing new, filtered arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
const records = array1.map((a, i) => [a, array2[i], array3[i]]);

const index = {};
records.filter(column => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(column);
  return key in index ? false : index[key] = true;
});
```

### Huh?

There are a lot of ways to solve this, with varying degrees of efficiency, and the best solution will depend on the size of your data. A simple but naïve solution iterates over each "column" and checks all of the preceding columns for equality. It looks like this:

```js
const array1 = [ 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
const array2 = [   5,   5,   7,   5];
const array3 = [true,true,true,true];

const newArray1 = array1.slice(0,1); // column 0 is never duplicate
const newArray2 = array2.slice(0,1);
const newArray3 = array3.slice(0,1);

// loop over columns starting with index 1
outer: for (let i = 1; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const a = array1[i];
  const b = array2[i];
  const c = array3[i];
  
  // check all preceding columns for equality
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (a === array1[j] && b === array2[j] && c === array3[j]) {
      // duplicate; continue at top of outer loop
      continue outer;
    }
  }

  // not a duplicate; add to new arrays
  newArray1.push(a);
  newArray2.push(b);
  newArray3.push(c);
}

console.log(newArray1);
console.log(newArray2);
console.log(newArray3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

As you can see, we have to check each row within each column for equality, every time. If you're curious, the complexity of this is ((+1)/2) (technically ((+1)/2), where  is 3 for three columns).

For a larger data sets it's advantageous to keep track of values you've already seen in a data structure that's quick to access: A hash, a.k.a. a JavaScript object. Since all of your values are primitive, a quick way to construct a key is `JSON.stringify`. Some might consider this a "hack"—and it's important to note that it will fail with values that can't be represented in JSON, e.g. `Infinity` or `NaN`—but it's a fast and easy one with data this simple.

```js
const array1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
const array2 = [5, 5, 7, 5];
const array3 = [true, true, true, true];

const newArray1 = [];
const newArray2 = [];
const newArray3 = [];

const index = {};

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const a = array1[i];
  const b = array2[i];
  const c = array3[i];
  const key = JSON.stringify([a,b,c]);
  
  if (key in index) {
    // duplicate; skip to top of loop
    continue;
  }
  
  // not a duplicate; record in index and add to new arrays
  index[key] = true;
  newArray1.push(a);
  newArray2.push(b);
  newArray3.push(c);
}

console.log(newArray1);
console.log(newArray2);
console.log(newArray3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

The complexity of this is (), or maybe (2) where , again,
 is 3 for three columns, and the 2 is another  to very roughly account for the cost of `JSON.stringify`. (Figuring out the cost of hash access is left as an exercise for the pedants among us; I'm content to call it (1).)

That's still pretty verbose. Part of the reason is that using three different variables for the data—which is really a single "table"—leads to a lot of repetition. We can preprocess the data to make it easier to deal with. Once it's "transposed" into a single two-dimensional array, we can use `Array.prototype.filter` with the key technique from above, for some very terse code:

```js
const array1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
const array2 = [5, 5, 7, 5];
const array3 = [true, true, true, true];

// turn "columns" into "rows" of a 2D array
const records = array1.map((a, i) => [a, array2[i], array3[i]]);

const index = {};
const newData = records.filter(column => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(column);
  return key in index ? false : index[key] = true;
});

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Of course, pre-processing isn't free, so this code isn't any more performant than the more verbose version; you'll have to decide how important that is to you. If you want you can now extract the columns from `newData` into three variables (`newData.forEach(([a,b,c]) => { newArray1.push(a); newArray2.push(b); /* ... */ })`), but for many purposes the "transposed" 2D array will be easier to work with.

Comment: The top answer is exactly what I was thinking when I read the question. I love the demonstration of different looks at it, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 Set https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Set -> lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

and then convert back to an array

check this snippet

```js
const array1 = ['A','B','A','B']
const array2 = [5,5,7,5]
const array3 = [true,true,true,true]

const uniqA1= new Set(array1)
const uniqA2= new Set(array2)
const uniqA3= new Set(array3)

console.log(Array.from(uniqA1))
console.log(Array.from(uniqA2))
console.log(Array.from(uniqA3))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't match OP's exemplary output - which seems counterintuitive, I admit.

Comment: That's not very well supported also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find duplicate elements with same indexes in all arrays and then filter out those elements.

```js
var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
  array2 = [5, 5, 7, 5],
  array3 = [true, true, true, true];

var dupes = []
var arrays = [array1, array2, array3];

arrays.forEach(function(arr, i) {
  arr.forEach((e, j) => !this[e] ? this[e] = true : dupes[i] = (dupes[i] || []).concat(j))
}, {})

var index = dupes[0].filter(e => dupes.every(a => a.includes(e)))
var result = arrays.map(e => e.filter((a, i) => !index.includes(i)))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Well, that's actually working for me. But is there any other simpler solution?

Comment: @Coyolero This answer doesn't eliminate "duplicate records" where each "column" is a "record" - as you confirmed in the comments above. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a couple of helper functions (lodash provides them also):

```js
let zip = (...arys) => arys[0].map((_, i) => arys.map(a => a[i]));
let uniq = (ary, key) => uniq2(ary, ary.map(key), new Set);
let uniq2 = (ary, keys, set) => ary.filter((_, i) => !set.has(keys[i]) && set.add(keys[i]))

// test

var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
var array2 = [5, 5, 7, 5];
var array3 = [true, true, true, true];

var [x, y, z] = zip(
    ...uniq(
        zip(array1, array2, array3),
        JSON.stringify
    )
);

console.log(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Interesting approach to "hash" records with `JSON.stringify`, but it fails when arrays include e.g. `NaN`, `Infinity`, `Symbol()`... you might want to add this to the description.

Comment: @le_m: sure, my point was rather to introduce some helpful generics.

Answer (score 0):

*Another* way, with [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp):

```js
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
array2 = [5, 5, 7, 5];
array3 = [true, true, true, true];

uniqueArray1 = array1.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return array1.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

uniqueArray2 = array2.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return array2.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

uniqueArray3 = array3.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return array3.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

console.log(uniqueArray1);
console.log(uniqueArray2);
console.log(uniqueArray3);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method I can think of is using an object to keep track, which will also coincidentally remove any duplicates as keys have to be unique. The only thing is I can think of how to extract it back into an array for now. I will think about it tomorrow.

This utilizes jquery for deep cloning. If you want it only in vanilla javascript, you could probably just implement a deep clone function.

```js
var array1 = [ 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
var array2 = [   5,   5,   7,   5];
var array3 = [true,true,true,true];

all_arrays = [array1, array2, array3];

let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < all_arrays[0].length; i++)
{
 let new_obj = recursive_objects(all_arrays, 0, i)
  $.extend(true, obj, new_obj);
}

console.log(obj);

function return_array(array, temp_obj)
{
 let keys = Object.keys(temp_obj);
  for (let key of keys)
  {
   
  }
}


function recursive_objects(arrays, arrays_index, index)
{
  let obj = {}
 
  if (arrays_index < arrays.length)
  {
    obj[arrays[arrays_index][index]] = recursive_objects(arrays, ++arrays_index, index);  
  }

  return obj;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```